# Does Journal of finance accept paper submissions done only in latex?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, latex

I have written my manuscript in template from the sharelatex website https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/journal-of-finance .
 I'm new to latex. Does the journal accept manuscripts in .pdf form written using Microsoft word.

Comment: Was the template just a description of required formatting, or was it an actual file - if so, in what format did it come? It would be somewhat unusual for a venue to point out a template whose format is incompatible with the format required for submission (though not absolutely impossible, especially when the template is hosted by someone else and there are several formats of the template to choose from).

Comment: Also: When referring to external resources and statements, please *link* to them.

Comment: @scaahu updated the question

Comment: Like all journals, submission guidelines ([pdf](http://www.afajof.org/SpringboardWebApp/userfiles/afa/file/Submissions/JF%20Submission%20Guidelines.pdf)) are available on their [site](http://www.afajof.org/details/page/2870711/Submissions.html).

Comment: Downvote removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the [Submit an Article](https://editorialexpress.com/cgi-bin/e-editor/e-submit_v12.cgi?dbase=jof) link  on [Journal of Finance](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/(ISSN)1540-6261), you'll find [guide to to creating PDF files](https://editorialexpress.com/e-editor/pdftips.html), there they say

> Windows: MS Word
>
> You can either install a pdf printer or use on online conversion service.

and they tell you where to get PDF Printer or Online Conversion services.

Obviously, they accept manuscripts in .pdf form written using Microsoft word.